# intellij: a required artifact is not listed by module descriptor: *#*!*.*

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I get these Exceptions when refreshing the sbt project within Intellij:

[image]

I removed `.intellij` folder but without success.

Anyway, it seems everything works as expected so far.

Here is the whole Project: https://github.com/pme123/play-binding-form

After the comment of Justin Kaeser I installed `2018.2` and now Intellij works, but now I see the exception in the `sbt shell:

```
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to formRoot (in build file:/Users/mpa/dev/Github/pme123/play-binding-form/)
[error] a required artifact is not listed by module descriptor: *#*!*.*
[error] a required artifact is not listed by module descriptor: *#*!*.*
[error] a required artifact is not listed by module descriptor: *#*!*.*
...
```

Comment: Hi @pme, can you please provide your project on github or at least a minimal working sample with this issue.

Comment: I added the project to the question - thanks for having a look.

Comment: Hi @pme Your welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found now the change that caused the problem:

In `build.sbt` my shared configuration:

```
lazy val shared = crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Pure)
  .settings(sharedSettings())
  .settings(sharedDependencies)
  .settings(
    publish := {},
    publishLocal := {},
    publishArtifact := false, // this line caused the problem
  )
```

When removing that line it works.

Would be great if someone knows the reason!

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a dependency resolving problem.

Also, in your sourcecode you have 2 projects with the same content root:

formRoot and play-finding-form.

You cannot have 2 modules with the same content root. 
Get Rid with one of them and fit your sbt build, File > Invalid Caches/Restart... and finally refresh all sbt project in the sbt tool window.

Hope it helps.

Comment: strange - you are right intellij shows me these 2 projects. But `sbt projects` only lists `formRoot`? So how can I fix the `build.sbt`?

Comment: You're using cross-projects, but IntelliJ is currently not able to fully support cross-projects (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12945). You may need to manually enable only the JS or JVM version if you want to work on one or the other from the IDE.

Comment: @JustinKaeser thanks - I think it could be related with https://github.com/mgilbertnz/idea-scalajs-bug - As since this update a lot of problems started.

Comment: Hi pme, @JustinKaeser, thanks for pointing out this interesting issues.